# Configure Android selinux to mount tmpfs filesystem

Tags: android-source, selinux

I'm trying to make a size limited tmpfs mount on Android AOSP for caching some HLS video in RAM. The video continuously rewrites so it can't be written to flash which would wear out. I can't figure out how to get the permissions right, any suggestions?

Also what domain should I use? I would like to restrict this directory so that only my app can use it, but that is not an absolute requirement.  My app is normal app, not privileged.

hls.te

```
type hlsfs, fs_type;

# Allow file access in /hls
allow domain hlsfs:file create_file_perms;
allow domain hlsfs:dir rw_dir_perms;
allow init hlsfs:dir { create_dir_perms relabelto };
```

file_contexts

```
#HLS cache
/data/hls(/.*)?              u:object_r:hlsfs:s0
```

init.rc

```
on init
    mkdir /data/hls 0777 system system
on early-fs
    mount tmpfs tmpfs /data/hls mode=777,size=60M,context=u:object_r:hlsfs:s0
```

error messages, first error is the mkdir, second the mount.

```
root@bpi-m64-hdmi:/ # dmesg | grep hls
[    2.218541] type=1400 audit(1499777970.690:4): avc:  denied  { associate } for  pid=1 comm="init" name="hls" scontext=u:object_r:hlsfs:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:rootfs:s0 tclass=filesystem permissive=1
[   11.285712] type=1400 audit(1499777979.750:6): avc: denied { relabelto } for pid=1 comm="init" name="hls" dev="dm-1" ino=170689 scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:hlsfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

Android default selinux policy is here https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/sepolicy/+/android-n-preview-2/

### Update:

I've made a lot of progress with this. First, it was a bad idea to put this in /data since there are many existing rules preventing that. So I moved it into /cache.

hls.te

```
type hlsfs, contextmount_type, fs_type;

# Allow file access in /hls
permissive hlsfs;
#allow domain hlsfs:file create_file_perms;
#allow domain hlsfs:dir rw_dir_perms;
```

file_contexts

```
#HLS cache
/cache/hls(/.*)?              u:object_r:hlsfs:s0
```

init.rc

```
on fs
    mkdir /cache/hls 0777 system system
    mount tmpfs tmpfs /cache/hls mode=777,size=60M,context=u:object_r:hlsfs:s0
```

init.te

```
# allow hls tmpfs to be mounted in cache dir
allow init cache_file:dir mounton;
```

With these changes I can mount the tmpfs directory. Next I need to make sure my app can use it.  I also need to make sure apps can't make anything executable in the tmp directory.

### Update2:

Apps can't get to the cache directory. So let's try another scheme...

This scheme is almost right. I can mount the tmpfs directory and my app can get to it. But the app can't get to it unless I change the owner "chown media_rw media_rw /data/media/0/hls". Changing the owner triggers the denial error from the core Android rules. I set init to permissive to bypass the error. So how do I get around the need to chown the directory? I tried setting permissions to 777 and mounting with gid=1023/uid=1023. Neither helps.

hls.te

```
# Allow file access in /hls
permissive hlsfs;
```

file_contexts

```
#HLS cache
/data/media/0/hls(/.*)?              u:object_r:hlsfs:s0
```

init.rc

```
on property:sys.boot_completed=1
    mkdir /data/media/0/hls 0777 media_rw media_rw
    mount tmpfs tmpfs /data/media/0/hls mode=777,size=60M,context=u:object_r:hlsfs:s0
    chown media_rw media_rw /data/media/0/hls
```

init.te

```
# allow hls tmpfs to be mounted in /data/media dir
allow init media_rw_data_file:dir {setattr mounton};
allow init hlsfs:dir {create setattr relabelto mounton};
allow init labeledfs:filesystem associate;

permissive init;
```

error message

```
07-14 23:02:33.010 1-1/? I/init: type=1400 audit(0.0:5): avc: denied { relabelto } for scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:hlsfs:s0 tclass=filesystem permissive=1
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have this working now. My last mistake was in trying to make a custom policy for the tmp directory. The custom policy led to the relabel error.

Now I have a working directory under getExternalStorageDirectory() which is tmpfs based with a 60MB limit.

init.te

```
# allow hls tmpfs to be mounted in /data/media dir
allow init media_rw_data_file:dir {setattr mounton};
allow init labeledfs:filesystem associate;
```

init.rc

```
on property:sys.boot_completed=1
    mkdir /data/media/0/hls 0777 media_rw media_rw
    mount tmpfs tmpfs /data/media/0/hls size=60M
```

sdcardd.te

```
allow sdcardd tmpfs:dir create_dir_perms;
allow sdcardd tmpfs:file create_file_perms;
```